# Dojo dijit/form/DateTextBox - customizing message for values out of range

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

In `dijit/form/DateTextBox` I can change the `data-dojo-props="constraints: { datePattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd', min: '2000', max: '2018'}, invalidMessage: 'Choose date as yyyy-mm-dd'"` to set format, range, and change the message shown when the date is in wrong format. But when the date is just out of the range 2000 to 2018 I get a different message. How to customize that one? Dojo documentation doesn't help - it says something about min and max, but doesn't state what message is shown neither how to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user the `rangeMessage` property:

```
data-dojo-props="constraints: { datePattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd', min: '2000', max: '2018'}, invalidMessage: 'Choose date as yyyy-mm-dd', rangeMessage: 'Choose a day between 2000 and 2018'"
```

This property is documented in the [Dojo Toolkit API](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/) reference. Select dijit/form/DateTextBox and make sure that 'Inheriteds' is checked.